# PyQT5 TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not Ui_MainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to build an app here. I used QT Designer to build the main window (Ui_MainWindow) with buttons. I import this to a new file where I can structure the code a bit better.

Anyhow, I keep getting the error "TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not Ui_MainWindow" whenever I try to get the filename via QFileDialog. This filename is used in the GetData -method to produce a dataframe. I'm sure I'm doing something horribly wrong here in my code. I understood that you can call methods within other methods

So I will have 3 buttons:

1. Open folder (which gets the filename)
2. Update data (which is connected to UpdateData method. This method updates the data as I want)
3. Calculate (a method that calculates something based on the output from updateData -method.)

So I am trying to get an output from step 1 to use as input in step 2, to get an output which then would be used as input in step 3 and then - voilá.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from myQTDesignerGUIfile import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QFileDialog, QMessageBox)
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QFileInfo
 
class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        #Build instance of setpUI in Ui_MainWindow -class
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
    def GetFileName(self):
        FileFilter = 'File (*.xlsx *.xlsm *.csv)'
        FileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent = self,
                                                caption="Select File",
                                                directory = 'Some Path',
                                                filter = FileFilter)[0]
        
        path = str(FileName)
        if path:
           print(path)
           return path

    def GetData(self):
        path = self.GetFileName
        return pd.read_csv(path)
    
    def UpdateData(self):
        ## get data using the GetData -method
        df = self.GetData()
        
        ## code to modify data is written here
        
        return final_mod_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyApp()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: The error you're reporting has no reference to the code above. Have you tried to manually edit the pyuic generated file? Besides, you're missing the parentheses of `GetFileName()` in `GetData()`, and, in any case, only classes and constants should have capitalized names, not variables and functions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll try editing the original pyuic file. Do you know where the error is referencing then?

Comment: No, you must ***NOT*** edit the pyuic file, **ever**! I asked if you did try to do that, because there's no reference to startfile in your script, so I'm supposing it's in another file, and that is the only other place it could be, unless you're using this script from *another one*.

Comment: Understood, thanks! So, what you're saying is that the problem might be in the myQTDesignerGUIfile -script? This is the pyuic file I generated from the command prompt. I have not done any edits to it. Only imported it to a new Python script with a class that inherits the Ui_MainWindow class from the myQTDesignerGUI file